# Artifactory storage structure

Tags: artifactory, diskspace

We where running out of storage, and I noticed that the reported "binaries size" from the monitoring console isn't coherent with the actual disk space on the artifactory server.
I see that in fact we use X2 storage over what’s artifactory monitor is reporting

I found that besides the filestore (usually at var/data/artifactory/filestote) there’s also another directory keeping all the binaries (at current/repositories path) and in fact making us use twice the size of storage.
Is that normal and expected?

Answer (score 1):

"current/repositories" appears to have got created as a result of Artifactory backups.
If the backup files are occupying too much space from the disk, consider incremental backups over frequent full backups. In addition, you may also consider utilising alternate options described in [JFrog Blog](https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-for-artifactory-backups-and-disaster-recovery/), for the backup strategy.

Comment: This indeed happened because of the internal backup setting. But it doesn't seem to behave correctly, since the fact that backups should be created (no matter if incremental or not) should not create another full copy of all the artifacts in the system on the disk. If it would all be created in a package at the designated backup location I would understand, but the files were just lying there in a folder, with no documentation to back it up. Furthermore, disabling the backups did not clear that folder.